# What would happen to the Dragonborn's soul if they died after doing some of the faction quests that involve Daedric Princes?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

In a few places throughout Skyrim it's hinted or otherwise stated that those who follow a Daedric Prince end up in that particular Prince's form of the afterlife in their plane of Oblivion. So vampires or other servants of Molag Bal would be sent to Coldharbour while a Nightingale would be sent to Nocturnal's realm of Evergloam. It also seems as though being Dragonborn grants you the right to enter Sovngarde for your afterlife regardless of race. In all of my playthroughs I've done enough side quests where it's safe to say multiple Daedric Princes have claims to my soul (Notably Sithis, Nocturnal, and Molag Bal, as well as the possibility to enter Sovngarde). My character is also a Dunmer which opens the possibility of the afterlife being the Cult of the Ancestors as described in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/181995/127963).

Should my character die, what would happen to her soul?

Comment: This is a great question.  It's related to, but not a duplicate of:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181991/afterlife-in-the-elder-scrolls-where-does-everyone-go-when-they-die

Comment: Given how many different immortal beings my PC's soul has been pledged to, there's going to be one hell of a scrap for their soul when they do actually die.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins or one big fight where the winner keeps the soul.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it's hard to be certain for the Dragonborn because, ultimately, his/her history has not been written yet.

But, if we look at The Champion of Cyrodiil, there is fairly strong evidence that they became Sheogorath.  The hints of this are in Sheogorath's dialog in Skyrim itself.

From this reddit thread:  https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Thread:398774

The dialog and related quests in ES4:

> In skyrim he says "You know,I was there for that whole sordid affair.Marvelous time! Butterflies,blood, a Fox,a severed head...Oh,and the cheese! To die for.
>
> U see butterflies-When u enter shivering isles whole room turn in butterflies
>
> Blood-Blood of Aedra and Deadra for Martin's quest.
>
> Fox-Gray Fox from thiefs guild
>
> Severed head-head of Mathieu Bellamont's mother in Dark brotherhood quest.
>
> Cheese-Quest for Sheogorath in Oblivion,where u must steal all cheese from  khajiit's.

If we assume that's true, and we also assume that The Champion of Cyrodiil also performed tasks for the other Daedric Lords, then it shows it's possible for one of the Lords to "win".  Now, admittedly, this is a lot of speculation and assumption, but there are hints.

So, what does this mean for the Dragonborn?  It means that one of the aspects will  "win" over the others.  For YOUR character, I think it's reasonable to pick who that is... but, we're going to have to wait until ES6 to hear/read about what happened to the canonical Dragonborn.

Now, in my opinion, the answer is:  The Dragonborn end up in Sovngarde... even if you're not a Nord.  There was some dialog there that hints that way.  (Emphasis below is mine)

> Tsun: "That was a mighty deed! The doom of Alduin encompassed at last, and cleansed is Sovngarde of his evil snare. They will sing of this battle in Shor's hall forever. But your fate lies elsewhere. When you have completed your count of days, **I may welcome you again, with glad friendship, and bid you join the blessed feasting.**"